# Gzip not working?

Tags: java, tomcat, gzip, tomcat8

It's not working event though it seems so easy ... I'm not sure how to debug. Help please?

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" KeystoreFile="/home/ec2-user/.keystore" KeystorePass="foobar" allowTrace="true" compression="on" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/json,text/javascript,text/css,text/plain,
application/javascript,application/xml,application/xml+xhtml"/>
```

Comment: Note that the default `compressionMinSize` is 2048, are you testing/verifying this with data that's over that size ?

Comment: Assuming that 2048 is bytes then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the attribute `useSendfile="false"`

As described here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

> `compression` ... Note: There is a tradeoff between using compression
>   (saving your bandwidth) and using the sendfile feature (saving your
>   CPU cycles). If the connector supports the sendfile feature, e.g. the
>   NIO connector, using sendfile will take precedence over compression.
>   ... You can turn off sendfile by setting `useSendfile` attribute of
>   the connector, ...
>
> `useSendfile` (`bool`) Use this attribute to enable or disable
>   sendfile capability. The default value is `true`. *Note that the use
>   of sendfile will disable any compression that Tomcat may otherwise
>   have performed on the response*.